# jquery listen to click event on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, event-delegation

I need to create a modal for html page. When a button on the page is clicked, the modals shows up. Button to close modal contains in the modal itself.

The problem is that click event on close button, that meant to remove a modal html from document, is not working. However, `console.log` assigned to the same event show up in console. Why is that happening and how to fix it?

Pen: https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/prZRYN

Js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#showModal').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').append(modalHtml)
  })

  $(document).on('click','#closeModal',function(){
    console.log('click triggered')
    $(document).remove('#modal')
 })

  var modalHtml = '<div id="modal"> <div class="modal-bg"></div><div class="modal-content"> <p>this is a modal</p><span id="closeModal">close</span> </div></div>'
})
```

Comment: The OP is already using a delegated event handler, that is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `remove()` directly on the element - use `$('#modal').remove()` instead - see demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showModal').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').append(modalHtml)
  })

  $(document).on('click', '#closeModal', function() {
    $('#modal').remove();
  })

  var modalHtml = '<div id="modal"> <div class="modal-bg"></div><div class="modal-content"> <p>this is a modal</p><span id="closeModal">close</span> </div></div>'
})
```

```css
#showModal {
  margin: 50px 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#modal {
  display: block;
}

#modal .modal-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#modal .modal-bg:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.5);
}

#modal .modal-content {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

#modal .modal-content #closeModal {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#modal .modal-content #closeModal:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="showModal"> Show modal</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this:

```
$(document).remove("#modal");
```

Where you should be doing this:

```
$("#modal").remove();
```

---

Also note that you don't need to wait until the DOM is ready to bind a handler to `document`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var modalHtml = '<div id="modal"> <div class="modal-bg"></div><div class="modal-content"> <p>this is a modal</p><span id="closeModal">close</span> </div></div>'

  $('#showModal').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').append(modalHtml)
  })
})

$(document).on('click', '#closeModal', function(){
    console.log('click triggered')
    $("#modal").remove()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to the use of the selector in `remove()`. That's used as a filter - not to find elements. To fix the logic select the element directly and call `remove()` on it:

```
$('#modal').remove();
```

[**Updated CodePen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJaxVO)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(document).remove('#modal');
```

to

```
$('#modal').remove();
```